# How to redirect to the root route

Tags: redirect, flask

I am clicking on a hidden input and passing it to a function on the server side to preform a function and redirect it back to the same page I was on.

```py
import random
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, session, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = '123456' # set a secret key for security purposes

@app.route("/")
def main_page():

    return render_template('index.html')
app.route("/process_money", methods = ["POST"])
def test_stuff():
    #will run function
    return redirect('/')
```

```html
                    <form action="/process_money" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="building" value="farm" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Find Gold!"/>
                    </form>
```

I'm getting a 404 not found error upon hitting the input button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route needs `@app`:

```
@app.route("/process_money", methods = ["POST"])
```

Comment: oh wow I was wondering what was going on i just forgot the @ i'm  now oof thanks so much